# Precise asymptotics of the sum of two square root functions

Tags: asymptotics

**Question:** Let $x_n$ be some term that goes to infinity as $n\rightarrow\infty$. I would like to know the precise asymptotics of $-\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt{x_n+4}$.

**My attempt:** We have
\begin{align*}
-\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt{x_n+4}
&=\sqrt{x_n}\left(-1+\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{x_n}}\right) \\
&=\sqrt{x_n}(-1+1+\epsilon_n) \\
&=\sqrt{x_n}\cdot\epsilon_n,
\end{align*}
where $\epsilon_n$ is some decaying function that I want the precise asymptotics of. Thanks.

Comment: $\epsilon_n\approx 2/x_n$ by Taylor's Theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your start is fine, now using the Taylor series
$$\sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{8}+\cdots$$
you obtain
$$\sqrt{x_n}\left(-1+1+\frac{2}{x_n}-\frac{2}{x_n^2}+\dots\right)=\frac{2}{x_n^{1/2}}-\frac{2}{x_n^{3/2}}+\dots\overset{x_n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$$
as the series is [alternating and monotonically decreasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test)

Answer (score 6):

$$\sqrt{x_n+4}-\sqrt{x_n}=\frac{4 }{\sqrt{x_n+4}+\sqrt{x_n}} \sim \frac{2 }{\sqrt{x_n}}$$